# How to Implement Dynamic SwiftUI View Hierarchy?

Tags: ios, user-interface, swiftui, declarative

I'm trying to implement a markdown renderer using SwiftUI. Markdown document contains a variety of blocks, where a block may be embedded in another block, for example, block quotes:

> Quote Level 1
>
> > Quote Level 2
> >
> > > Quote Level 3
> > >
> > > > ...

The entire document forms a tree-like structure with arbitrary depth, requiring the renderer to take a recursive approach. I adopted the following code structure:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func renderBlock(block: Block) -> some View {
    switch block {
    // other types of elements
    case let block as BlockQuote:
        HStack {
            GrayRectangle()
            ForEach(block.children) { child in
                renderBlock(child) // recursion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the compiler rejects that as it require the return type to be determined during compile phase. Is it possible to generate dynamic view structure like this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 1):

ViewHierarchy.swift:

```
 import SwiftUI

 @main
 struct ViewHierarchyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(tree: mockData())
        }
    }
 }

 func mockData() -> [Tree] {
    let tree2: [Tree] = [Tree(id: 2, title: "2", items: [])]
    let tree1: [Tree] = [Tree(id: 1, title: "1", items: []),
                         Tree(id: 11, title: "11", items: []),
                         Tree(id: 12, title: "12", items: tree2)]
    let tree: [Tree] = [Tree(id: 0, title: "Root", items: tree1)]
    return tree
 }
```

Model.swift:

```
 class Tree: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let items: [Tree]
    
    init(id: Int, title: String, items: [Tree]) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.items = items
    }
 }
```

ContentView.swift:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    let tree: [Tree]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(tree, id: \.id) { treeItem in
                TreeViewItem(item: treeItem) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("-")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 struct TreeViewItem<Content: View>: View {
    let item: Tree
    let content: Content

    init(item: Tree, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.item = item
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.title)
            ForEach(item.items, id: \.id) { treeItem in
                TreeViewItem(item: treeItem) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("-")
                    } as! Content
                }
            }
        }
        content
    }
 }
```

Output:

[image]